# Move logo to center from right Html CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a logo on the right side of the page. On resizing(making window smaller) I want to move the logo to the center of the page.

Here's my CSS

```
.headerlogo {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    z-index: 999;
}

.getapp-nav-img{
    height: 60px;
        margin: auto;
}
```

Here's my HTML

```
<div class="headerlogo" style="">
                    <div class="social-nav">
                        <a href='#'><img class="getapp-nav-img" src='img/logo.png'/></a>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

Its not moving by this. How can I achieve this?

Comment: tell the breakpoint, accordingly one can suggest d same, using `media` query.

Comment: @Abhishek please check my snippet answer and show in full page and check responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use media queries like this:

```css
.headerlogo {
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin: 50px 5% 0 auto;
    z-index: 999;
}

.getapp-nav-img {
    height: 60px;
    margin: auto;
} 

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .headerlogo {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="headerlogo" style="">
  <div class="social-nav">
    <a href='#'><img class="getapp-nav-img" src='https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/black-icon-social-media/256/099280-blinklist-logo.png'/></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle for easier testing: https://jsfiddle.net/ajjr3u3n/2/

Comment: on using this logo is moving to left on resizing and not center

Comment: @Abhishek Check the updated answer and jsfiddle I posted.

Comment: @Abhishek are you sure? At least it works for me in the fiddle and also in the snippet. Not sure if there is something more I'm missing from your css or html.

Comment: I also altered your margins and removed the  `margin-right` and `margin-left` attributes and made them into a single `margin` attribute. Not just the media query was added.

Comment: @thepio added text-align: center in the media query and then it worked! :) thanks :)

Comment: Oh ok. So you had some other css affecting the page I did not know about. But cool that you got it working. Will update my answer also since this makes the answer more "bullet proof" if you will.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the float and use text-align to center the img. You need to make those changes within a `media query` like this:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .social-nav {
       text-align: center;
    }
    .headerlogo {
        float: none;
    }
}
```

---

Link to jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/e0d8my79/108/